# Next js + node js cookie issue in prod env

Tags: node.js, next.js, cookies

Setup works perfectly in local env. Issue erase when I host it in AWS. Node.js/Express running in AWS Fargate, docker, behind ALB. Next.js (v 14) hosted in amplify. Both frontend and backend is https.

I'm sending request using server actions in Next js:

```
 const res = await fetch(`${appConfig.BASE_URL}${loginUrl}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
})
```

In node js I have a cors() middleware with following settings

```
const corsOption = {
  origin: [appConfig.FRONT_END_BASE_URL, appConfig.FRONT_END_ADMIN_URL],
  preflightContinue: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With'],
  credentials: true,
```

}

This is login controller where I sending cookie back to client

```
 res.cookie('accessToken', sessionToken, {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
    })
```

However when I inspect a network call I can see that server respond with a cookie, but browser not set it.

here is a request

[image]

here is a response

[image]

But it's no cookie set

[image]

This is happen for Brave and Firefox, however in Chrome I can see cookie been set, but I still can't login, looks like Next js can't read it or whatever.

I'm accessing a cookie in Next js using  cookies module from 'next/headers'

Please help to figured out what is the issue here. Struggling with it 3 days already.

My guess maybe it somehow related to the fact that I sending request from server actions, which technically  not a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some consideration I just move everything to a same domain.

FE - https://example.com
BE - https://server.example.com

Then I have to specify domain property when sending response:

```
 res.cookie('accessToken', sessionToken, {
        domain: appConfig.DOMAIN,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        secure: true,
      })
```

It should be with dot at the begining `.example.com`

After this everything work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents

First of all, please include this in your headers of your fetch request.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
```

Secondly
I guess you do not explicitly save cookies from your express backend. Why don't you try to save it and see the results?

/api/login/route.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    const { accessToken } = await request.json()

    const res = await fetch(`${appConfig.BASE_URL}${loginUrl}`, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // I did not understand why you add this to the header..
        },
    })

    const cookieHeader = res.headers.get("Set-Cookie")

    const data = await res.json()

    const response = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(res.data))

    if (cookieHeader) {
        response.headers.set("Set-Cookie", cookieHeader)
    }

    return response
}
```

I have the following result
[image: Result]

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", is a wildcard, I want to make request from specific origin only. Since origin specified, I have to use 'credentials': 'include'.
I'm authenticate user thru firebase on a client side, then I sending firebase ID token to my backend, to exchange it for sessionToken token. This is why you see this: Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`.
Just to clarify:  I'm NOT using Next.js route handlers as in your example. It works perfectly in localhost. Problem is when its https and prod env.

Comment: 1) Is it behind a proxy? 2) Take a look at this https://community.fly.io/t/http-only-cookie-not-being-set-in-production-with-nextjs-django/13802/5

Comment: This is looks complicated. I solve it different way. But thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Please share your solution with us